# Simple Harmonic Motion Question - Block on Platform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator

A platform is executing SHM in a vertical direction with an amplitude of $5$ cm and a frequency of $\frac{10}{\pi}$ vibrations per second. A block is placed on the platform at the lowest point of its path.

$a)$ At what point will the block leave the platform?

$b)$ How far will the block rise above the highest point reached by the platform?

For part $a)$ I'm not even sure how to tackle it...From my understanding, the block would leave the platform when it has an acceleration that exceeds gravity, but I don't know when that would be? I'm just very confused about the entire problem, and i'm having a hard time visualizing it as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will assume that the motion of the platform will not be affected by the placement of the block, either because the platform is being forced to perform this SHM or because the platform if performing this motion due to a linear spring, but the mass of the block is insignificantly small compared to the mass of the platform.

The block has two forces acting upon it: platform is excreting a normal force and gravity. The normal force can only exert an upward force on the block (it can't pull the block down). So at the moment the block would have to experience a downward normal force to keep following the trajectory of the platform, it will leave the platform.

This moment can be found using the acceleration of the platform and Newton's second law.
The position of the platform as a function of time, $h(t)$, starting at the lowest point, will look like this:
$$
h(t)=-A\cos(\omega t)
$$
where $A$ is the peak amplitude (I am not sure if the given amplitude is the peak of peak-to-peak amplitude) and $\omega$ is the angular frequency ($\omega=2\pi f$).
The acceleration, $\ddot{h}(t)$, easily be derived:
$$
\ddot{h}(t)=A\omega^2\cos(\omega t)
$$
And using Newton's second law we can find a relation between acceleration and the normal force, $F_n$ if the block would stick to the platform:
$$
\sum{F}=F_n(t)-mg=m\ddot{h}(t)
$$
From here it can be solved at which time the normal force will be downwards/negative.

After this the block will have the same velocity as the platform at the moment of release, but after that it will only experience the force of gravity (until it would hit the platform again).

Comment: Pretty bad answer, in my opinion, sorry. Keep in mind that both the amplitude and the frequency of oscillation will change when the block is added, so you can't use the same equations that applied earlier for the platform, willy-nilly like that.

Comment: @PhysicsLlama since the question talks about executing a SHM I assumed that the platform might be being forced to perform this SHM, I will edit my answer to include this assumption.

Comment: Yes, it's being forced to perform this SHM, but because of the spring. Thus the amplitude and frequency that correspond to this SHM will be different than the other amplitude and frequency, which corresponds to both the platform and block's SHM. Thanks for taking this into consideration.

Comment: Referring to part b) of the question, why would the block rise above the highest point reached by the platform? As the platform moves up, it will decelerate, so why should it throw the block above the highest point reached by the platform?